# Set name attribute programatically in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

This is probably an easy one. I have an `*ngFor="let i of Items"`, and within that scope an anchor

```
<a name=""></a>
```

and I want the value of name to be a hash of *i*.

So I made a

`public getAnchor(i: Item): string`

in the .ts file.

However, `<a name="getAnchor(i)"></a>` does not call the function, but renders as it is written. And `<a name="{{ getAnchor(i) }}"></a>` makes the page crash.
I'm an angular novice. Tell me what I should do :)

Comment: Whatever the language or technology is, if you get a error, you should read it. And if you don't understand it, you should post it.

Comment: Of course. I am having a hard time debugging angular in web developer, as I simply get a WDS Disconnected, and I haven't figured out to curb that error, and get the actual error message or at least call stack.

Comment: Open the console of your web browser, where the page crashes. If it really "crashes", then you'll have an error there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular 2 the convention was to do this:

`[attr.name]="getAnchor(i)"`

Not sure if this is still the same in Angular 6. You can give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind attributes like this

```
<a [name]="getAnchor(i)"></a>
```

or This

```
<a [attr.name]="getAnchor(i)"></a>
```

Note: I am not sure about 2nd method.

Comment: If you're not sure, why don't you test it before posting it?

Comment: It was available in older versions. That's why i just mention it.